# Pigeon Hole Principle: Six positive integers whose maximum is at most $14$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I was reading this example from my textbook:

> Let $S$ be a set of six positive integers whose maximum is at most $14$.
>   Show that the sums of the elements in all the nonempty subsets of $S$
>   cannot all be distinct.
>            For each nonempty subset $A$ of $S$ the sum of the elements in A denoted $S$ satisfies: $1 \leq S \leq 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 69 $
>
> And
>   then there are $2^6 - 1 = 63$ non empty subsets of $S$.

Could somebody please explain me the logic of $63$. How is this being calculated.

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: Just for curiosity: since there are more possible results than subsets, how does the textbook finish the problem? (If it is long, don't bother).

Comment: The book is assuming you know that a finite set with n elements will have $2^n $ subsets including the empty set and the entire set itself.  Do you know why?

Comment: Ajotaxte.  Min sum is min elements.  Max sum is min elements + 10+11+12+13+14.  Max minus min is 60 < 63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the six integers as either being in the subset or not in the subset. Each integer can have 2 states.  For a total of $2^6=64$ total states or subsets. Subtracting out the empty set, you are left with 63 subsets.

Answer (score 0):

We denote the size, or cardinality, of $S$ by $|S|=6$. Now for any nonempty set $X$ there are $2^{|X|}$ subsets of $X$ in total, these include $X$ itself and the empty set $\varnothing$.

So for your set there are $2^{|S|}=2^6$ subsets of $S$ in total. Since the empty set $\varnothing$ is empty by definition you must subtract $1$ from $2^6$ to obtain the number of nonempty sets.